# Is there any problem if my SPFx requires "node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0" while my node.js version is "14.18.1"

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, nodejs

I want to deploy this SPFx sample inside my tenant @ https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-chatgpt-app. Now inside the `package.json` file below is mentioned regarding the node version:

```
{
  "name": "react-chat-gpt-message-extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0"
  },
```

While my `node.js` command prompt has this version:

```
C:\Windows\System32>node -v
v14.18.1
```

Now I build >> deployed and tested the web part and it is working well.

So is there any issue or compatibility issue I am unaware of? and should I upgrade my `node.js` command prompt to use node version which is in between `"node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0"` ?

Comment: Which version of SPFx generator are you using? Check `@microsoft/sp-core-library` in `package.json` file.

Comment: @GaneshSanap i am have this version `"@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.16.1",` ? why you are asking .. thanks?

Comment: For this version of SPFx generator, ideally you should use node js `v16.13+`.

Comment: @GaneshSanap but the web part got deployed using node v14 without issues.. so should i upgrade or i should be fine

Comment: I think it should be fine as it is deployed and working fine. Let's also wait for other experts comments.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For SPFx generator v1.16.1, it is recommended by Microsoft to use node js `v16.13+`.

For detailed list of compatible versions of SPFx generator and Node.js, you can follow this compatibility matrix documentation: [SharePoint Framework development tools and libraries compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility)

[image]